# Infinite slider/caroussel that flicks with React/Next & Tailwind CSS

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, carousel

I'm working with an infinite slider/caroussel with React specifically Next.js and Tailwind CSS. I did my component but the animation flicks after some time after my logo did a loop, is there a way to fix that?

TSX file

```
import * as React from "react";
import Image from "next/image";
import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";
import Photo from "../../public/Profile-Picture.jpg";
import { Icon } from "@iconify/react";

export default function Home() {
  const images = ["skill-icons:javascript", "skill-icons:typescript"];

  return (
    <div className="xl:container mx-auto ">
      <div className=" flex items-center min-h-screen justify-center">
        <div className="w-[200%] h-20 border-t border-b border-gray-600 overflow-hidden relative">
          <div className="w-[200%] flex items-center h-20 justify-around absolute left-0 gap-20 animate">
            {images.map((i,index) => {
              return (
                <div className="flex justify-center items-start w-[20rem]">
                  <img key={index} src={i} />
                </div>
              );
            })}
            {images.map((i) => {
              return (
                <div className="flex justify-center items-start w-[20rem]">
                  <img key={index} src={i} />
                </div>
              );
            })}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
      );
}
```

CSS file

```
@keyframes scroll {
  0% {
    left: 0;
  }
  100% {
    left: -100%;
  }
}

.animate {
  animation: scroll 5s linear infinite;
}
```

Comment: Have a second copy of the images and translate by -50% instead of -100%. If you need more help please put a runnable snippet into your question.

Comment: Nope it doesn't fix it